# Flag history page looks weird on mobile

Tags: bug, mobile-web, flag-history

Platform: Android 5.1, Google Chrome 58.0.3029.83
Random event. Has a chance to occur, but not 100%.

Some texts are small while others are big. Are they fugu?

> [image: Hello]

Comment: No repro. Android 7. Same Chrome version.

Comment: Think it's something with device or browser app settings, saw it before, can't find it now. Maybe deleted. (something with dynamic or "friendly" font)